# Oracle APEX: How can I hide IG APEX$ROW_SELECTOR programmatically

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

Is there a way to hide APEX$ROW_SELECTOR programmatically to make it read only when a certain condition is met?

For example if I do a check for a value of a hidden page item on page load and based on the value of that page item what to hide selector column in my grid

Comment: Let me know if you are expecting what I have created in the below example. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/workspace_akil/r/test/hide-show-row-selector

Comment: Not quite. I need the checkbox disabled or hidden. Not for one row though but for the whole grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want this to be done programatically when we have an easy solution.

You can Hide/Show using the the **Server-side condition** of the column (Refer screenshot)

[image]

In this example if the Page Item (P44_SHOW_HIDE_RS) is **'Y'** then  the APEX$ROW_SELECTOR column will be visible else it will be hidden.

You can try out this link
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/workspace_akil/r/test/hide-show-row-selector